# Better way to Select to an async Func?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, select, func

I've been refactoring a common pattern in my project and found it's not as simple as using a LINQ `Select` to an async function.

For context, here is how it is done currently.

```
async Task<ICollection<Group>> ExecuteQueryGroupsForDomain(DomainInfo domain, int batchSize, CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        return await BlahBlahActuallyGoGetGroupsForDomainHere(domain, batchSize, ct);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

var executeQueries = new List<Func<CancellationToken, Task<ICollection<Group>>>>();

domains.ForEach(domain =>
    executeQueries.Add(async (ct) =>
        await ExecuteQueryGroupsForDomain(domain, 123, ct)));
```

---

Now if I try to replace the `ForEach` loop section using LINQ:

```
var executeQueries = domains.Select(domain =>
    async (ct) => await ExecuteQueryGroupsForDomain(domain, 123, ct));
```

It complains `Type arguments cannot be inferred by the usage` which leads me to believe I'm not returning anything from the `Select`, but I clearly am returning the `Func` I want.

Is there a better way of creating a list of `Func`'s, ideally avoiding explicit casts?  Also is there any explanation why the compiler is unable to infer the type when the `Select`'d async method is clearly telling it what the type should be?

---

To be clear, I do need to pass the `CancellationToken` to the `Func`'s because it is a different token than the external one (specifically, it is a linked token tying the external one to another internal one).

Comment: Do you really want to start all of those async tasks at the same time?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yes each task will be fetching some data over the network independent of each other and the server can handle much more than the concurrent load I'll be putting on it briefly.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 tried that, same problem. I also tried without any semblance of a cancellation token and am seeing no change so the token has no impact here.

Comment: `domains.Select(async domain => await Execute(...))` should work but you lose the CT parameter. But see the answer below. It's kinda minimal but he's right. The types can't be inferred and you'll need to be explicit

Comment: `Also is there any explanation why the compiler is unable to infer the type when the Select'd async method is clearly telling it what the type should be?` - `Func` and `Action` are not the only delegate types. There could be any number of delegate types that match that signature, and that's why the compiler doesn't know which one you want.

Comment: Since your lambda isn't performing any processing after await, it doesn't need to be async. Also note that each task is only started when the select is enumerated, and will be restarted if the returned IEnumerable is enumerated twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the returns of the select, for the compiler is not clear what the type of the return is. So, you need to explicitly the type of the return, here are 2 ways:

```
executeQueries = domains.Select(domain => 
    new Func<CancellationToken, Task<ICollection<Group>>>(token => 
        this.ExecuteQueryGroupsForDomain(domain, 123, token))).ToList();

executeQueries = domains
    .Select<DomainInfo, Func<CancellationToken, Task<ICollection<Group>>>>(domain =>
        ct => this.ExecuteQueryGroupsForDomain(domain, 123, ct)).ToList();
```

======================================================================

EDIT 1:
The compiler can't infer the type from a lambda expression because a lambda is just a shorthand for an anonymous method, not a type. So, you need to be explicitly and indicate the return type of the method, if the return is a base Delegate or other delegate type, like Action, Func, etc. Review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11587644/2844593) other answer, where explain the error compiler based on the C# 4 spec.

If you need transform your original code in something more readable, I don't think there is another way more readable. Here are other ways the code can be written:

```
foreach (var domain in domains) {
    executeQueries.Add(token => this.ExecuteQueryGroupsForDomain(domain, 123, token));
}
executeQueries.AddRange(domains
    .Select(domain => (Func<CancellationToken, Task<ICollection<Group>>>) (token => 
        this.ExecuteQueryGroupsForDomain(domain, 123, token))));
executeQueries =
    (from domain in domains
    select new Func<CancellationToken, Task<ICollection<Group>>>(token => 
        this.ExecuteQueryGroupsForDomain(domain, 123, token))).ToList()
```

Comment: Okay that worked, thanks.   Not sure why the compiler can't infer the type though, the method clearly returns it any explanation there?  I was hoping for something a little more readable though, I'd argue this is worse than the `ForEach` loop I have written. is there any other way to infer the type perhaps a static-method that knows the types beforehand or something?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the `Func`'s?

You can use the following if the actual `CancellationToken` is already present.

```
// create and start a Task for each domain
var executeQueryTasks = domains.Select(domain => ExecuteQueryGroupsForDomain(domain, 123, ct));

// wait until all tasks are finished and get the result in an array
var executedQueries = await Task.WhenAll(executeQueryTasks);
```

Comment: I do need the `Func`'s. The cancellation token present is an external one, whereas the one I'm passing to the `Func`'s is a linked token that ties the external one to a separate internal one.

Answer (score 1):

You may gain some readability by using an extension method like the one below. It takes the same arguments with the LINQ [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) method, but returns task-factories instead of materialized tasks.

```
public static IEnumerable<Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>>> SelectTaskFactory
    <TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> selector)
{
    return source.Select(item =>
    {
        return new Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>>(ct => selector(item, ct));
    });
}
```

Usage example:

```
var executeQueries = domains.SelectTaskFactory(async (domain, ct) =>
{
    return await ExecuteQueryGroupsForDomain(domain, 123, ct);
}).ToList();
```

The type of the `executeQueries` variable is `List<Func<CancellationToken, Task<ICollection<Group>>>>`.